# jQuery .animate width: 'show'/'hide' from other side

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Simple question. I've got some window tools in right-top corner and I want them to show on hover. Pretty simple I've done it with

```
d.animate({ width: 'show',opacity:0.7},120);
```

All works good and fine, but it slides from left to right. It would look much more better if it would do it from right to left. Is it possible to simple change it without expanding code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/thHZ9/

If you are positioning the element absolutely, make sure you're positioning it by its right side, not its left:

```
#cool{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;

    ...
}​
```

Comment: I've got custom number of 'tools', and one is under another. I cant use position:absolute becouse tools quaintly is not constant

Comment: The concept is the same. You want to position the element from its right side, whether this be `float:right` or something else.